# jQuery Datepicker - Half Day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Has anyone come across a method of being able to choose half a day using a jquery datepicker? Basically, I'd like users to be able to select from Monday PM to Friday AM, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Jquery plugin

[jQuery UI Timepicker](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timepicker-by-fgelinas)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. In the meantime I've also found http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/. I'm sure there's a way of customising either of these to just morning or afternoon.

Comment: By making the plugin increment in 12 hour steps, I can basically force it to think in AM/PM mode.